how to make the user not repeat the item (productname) in the datagridview with the cellendedit and EditingControlShowing events in the vb.net
I'm trying to make the user not repeat the item (productname) in the datagridview with the cellendedit and EditingControlShowing events in the vb.net.
You can see the gif file in this post 2 items are repeated or duplicate.
Or is there another method or have to use another datagridview event, please guide me
Thanks
Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' To reduce the flickering...
        DataGridView1.GetType().
    GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic).
    SetValue(DataGridView1, True)
        updateDataSource()
    End Sub
   Protected Sub updateDataSource()
        dictProducts = ProductFinaltestingService.GetDistinctProducts().
    ToDictionary(Function(p) p.ToString(), Function(p) p)
        BindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of ProductFinaltesting)}
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
        DataGridView1.Columns("Unit").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("No").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("Prp").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("Prs").ReadOnly = True
        BindingSource1.AddNew()
        DataGridView1.Select()
    End Sub
 Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(
      sender As Object,
      e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles _
      DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox Then
            Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
            Dim tb = DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox)
            If dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
                If tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Count = 0 Then
                    tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
                    tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(dictProducts.Keys.ToArray())
                End If
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
            Else
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
            End If
        End If
    End Sub Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(
        sender As Object,
        e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        Dim src = DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, BindingSource)
        If src.Count = e.RowIndex Then Return
        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
            Dim p As ProductFinaltesting = Nothing
            Dim key = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value?.ToString().Trim()

            If key Is Nothing Then Return
            If dictProducts.TryGetValue(key, p) Then
                Dim boundItem = TryCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting)
                  If p.Unit <> boundItem.Unit Or p.Prp <> boundItem.Prp Or p.Prs <> boundItem.Prs Then
                    boundItem.Unit = p.Unit
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prp = p.Prp
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prp").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prs = p.Prs
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prs").Index, e.RowIndex)

                End If
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
                Btnsave.Visible = True
            End If
            setno()
        End If
        Dim QTY As Integer = Nothing
        If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("QTY").Value IsNot Nothing Then
            If Not Integer.TryParse(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("QTY").Value.ToString(), QTY) Then
                QTY = 0
            End If
        Else
            QTY = 0
        End If
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("QTY").Value = QTY
    End Sub
  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(
       sender As Object,
       e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) _
       Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index AndAlso
           e.RowIndex <> dgv.NewRowIndex Then
            Dim key As String

            If dgv.IsCurrentCellInEditMode Then
                Dim p = dictProducts.Values.
                FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.ProductName.
                Equals(e.FormattedValue.
                ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))

                If p IsNot Nothing Then
                    key = p.ToString()
                Else
                    key = e.FormattedValue.ToString()
                End If
            Else
                key = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value?.ToString().Trim()
            End If
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(key) OrElse
           Not dictProducts.ContainsKey(key) Then
                Dim boundItem = DirectCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting)
                boundItem.Unit = Nothing
                boundItem.Prp = Nothing
                boundItem.Prs = Nothing
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Invalid Product!"
                Btnsave.Visible = False
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("PRP").Index, e.RowIndex)
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("PRS").Index, e.RowIndex)
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
        Dim cell As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = TryCast(DataGridView1(2, e.RowIndex), DataGridViewTextBoxCell)
        If cell IsNot Nothing Then
            If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("Qty") Then
                Dim chars() As Char = e.FormattedValue.ToString().ToCharArray()
                For Each c As Char In chars
                    If Char.IsDigit(c) = False Then
                        MessageBox.Show("You have to enter digits only")
                        e.Cancel = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next c
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
   Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidated(
       sender As Object,
       e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidated
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
            Dim p As ProductFinaltesting = Nothing
            Dim key = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value?.ToString().Trim()

            If key Is Nothing Then Return
            If dictProducts.TryGetValue(key, p) Then
                Dim boundItem = TryCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting)
    If boundItem Is Nothing Then Return
                If p.Unit <> boundItem.Unit Or p.Prp <> boundItem.Prp Or p.Prs <> boundItem.Prs Then
                    boundItem.Unit = p.Unit
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prp = p.Prp
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prp").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prs = p.Prs
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prs").Index, e.RowIndex)

                End If

                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
                Btnsave.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        If keyData = Keys.Enter AndAlso CBool(Keys.Enter) Then
            If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Productname").Value?.ToString()) And Not CInt(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Qty").Value) = 0 Then
                    BindingSource1.AddNew()
End If
Else
                Return True
            End If
   End If

        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function
Public Class ProductFinaltesting

    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property No As Integer?
    Public Property ProductName As String
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Prp As Integer?
    Public Property Prs As Integer?

    Public Property Qty As Integer?

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{ProductName}"
    End Function
End Class



